# Set notation for an indexed family

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I want to represent a family of open balls by [set-builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation).

Let $M = (X,d)$ be a metric space. The open ball in $M$ is
$$
B_r (x) = \{y \in X~|~d(y,x) < r\}
$$
Define the collection of open balls
$$
\mathcal{B_{x}} = \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \{B_{1/n}(x)\}
$$

Then, are the following set notations for $\mathcal{B}_{x}$ correct and formal?
$$
\{B_{1/n}(x)~|~n \in \mathbb{N}\}\\
\{B_{r}(x)~|~r=\frac{1}{n},~n \in \mathbb{N}\}\\
\{A \in X~|~\exists n \in \mathbb{N}:r=\frac{1}{n} \land A = B_{r}(x)~\}
$$

Comment: First two are okay. In the third, it should be $A\subseteq X$. And you can't assign $r=1/n$ after "$:$". The correct way to say it would be $\{A\subseteq X|\exists n\in\Bbb N:A=B_r(x)\text{ where }r=1/n\}$.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Oops, what I meant was $A \subseteq X$. Thank you! Can I replace 'where' with just a comma? $A = B_r(x), r = 1/n$

Comment: I'm not sure why you wouldn't just write $B_{\frac{1}{n}}(x)$ in that instance.

Comment: Eh... I think you should be alright using a comma. But the meaning of comma in many contexts means "conjunction" so it could be interpreted as identical to what you have written now by some people.